# postgres debezium returning different dates format

Tags: postgresql, debezium

I got a postgres debezium connector running and I can see even the data on database looks like :

```
effectivedates_effectivestartdate | date
 
effectivedates_effectiveenddate 
---------------------------------+--------
 9999-12-31
```

when I check the CDC topics the data appears to be like :

```
}, "effectivedates_effectiveenddate": { "string": "10000-12-31" }
```

and data is landing on S3 buckect like :

```
max(after.effectivedates_effectiveenddate AS `effectivedates_effectiveenddate`)|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|10000-12-31                                                                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

so I wonder if anyone knows that is causing this behaviour. Is there a configuration parameter that might help to fix this. thanks.

Comment: Please share your connector configuration.

Comment: @Naros this is the config:
  
    "decimal.handling.mode":"string",  
    "transforms.changeTopicNameMaster.regex": "mdm\\.public\\.(.*)", 
    "converters": "timestampConverter",
    "timestampConverter.type":  "oryanmoshe.kafka.connect.util.TimestampConverter",   
    "database.server.name": "xxx",
    "transforms.changeTopicNameMaster.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
    "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
    "name": "source_debezium_preprod",  
    "max.batch.size": "10000",